# Is there a more efficient method of getting end of day?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

I have a DATETIME variable `@DateEnd = '1/4/2011 16:43:22 PM'`.  I want to get the end of day: `1/4/2011 23:59:59.997`.

I have the following and it works fine, but it has lots of conversions and doesn't seem efficient:

```
DECLARE @DateString VARCHAR(25)
DECLARE @DateEnd DATETIME = '1/4/2011 16:43:22 PM'

SET @DateString = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @DateEnd, 101) + ' 23:59:59.997'
SET @DateEnd = CAST(DateString AS DATETIME)
```

Is there a more efficient method of accomplishing this?

Comment: There is no reliable "end of day." See [Dating Responsibly](https://sqlblog.org/dates#between), particularly the links in the `BETWEEN` section.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typically what we do is get the 0/midnight value for the start of the next day, and then use an exclusive inequality boundary (`<`) for that end of the range instead of an inclusive equality boundary (`<=`).

```
DECLARE @DateEnd DATETIME = '20110104 16:43:22'
SET @DateEnd = DATEADD(day, 1, Cast(@DateEnd as Date))
```

---

It's also **NEVER** okay to format a datetime literal for SQL like in the question. Different cultures and languages have their own norms and expectations around how dates should look, and it's not good to force your own personal or cultural norms into those languages. SQL, as its own language, is no different. If you're writing SQL and not using SQL's format for the date values (`yyyyMMdd`, `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss[.fff]`, or `yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss[.fff]`), you have a *WRONG* format for that context.

For example, my own preferred format, coming to SQL later after first learning a few other (procedural) languages, is `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`, which doesn't quite match those acceptable formats. I admit I've used that format quite a lot over the years; you can probably find examples in my answers here on Stack Overflow. But every place where I did that was **wrong**, and I no longer use it. So don't take it too hard; everybody has to learn this.

Comment: This is the real answer: *always* compare datetimes using a half-open interval `>= AND <`

Comment: Too many sprocs had the 23:59:59.997 pattern with the subsequent `dt between @start and @end` and I didn't want to mess with it.  I ended up biting the bullet and made the change everywhere.  Hopefully I didn't break anything.

Comment: I'd **really** like to see a new "`BETWEENEX`" operator that does an exclusive check on the upper bound.

Answer (score 1):

One little cheat is `format()`.   However, if `@DateEnd` is being used as a date range, you may be better off using `< TheNextDay`

```
Declare @DateEnd datetime = '1/4/2011 16:43:22 PM'

Set @DateEnd = format(@DateEnd,'yyyy-MM-dd 23:59:59.997')
```

**Just another option avoiding Format()**

```
Declare @DateEnd datetime = '1/4/2011 16:43:22 PM'
Set @DateEnd = concat(convert(date,@DateEnd),' 23:59:59.997')
```

Comment: Ha, that is a neat trick.  Sadly, this method is quite a bit slower.

Comment: @AngryHacker Is it being resolved only once or for every record?

Comment: @AngryHacker I would never suggest using format on big data, but a one-off variable ?  ...  I'm having a hard time understanding your "quite a bit slower"

Comment: @AngryHacker I suspect this is part of a function.  An updated option, 1 convert and 1 string operation

Comment: It's being done on a pretty large recordset.  The performance isn't bad but since it's a set, I always look for improvements.

Comment: @AngryHacker I get that.   Made a little tweak

Comment: If being done via a User Defined function, that will have a cost as well.   Consider an inline approach   concat(convert(date,YourDateColumn,' 23:59:59.997')

Comment: Maybe specify format 23?

Comment: @shawnt00 Sure, it's not wrong, but I'm not sure what it buys me.   Concat() will handle the implicit conversion and bonus I save a few key strokes :)

Comment: Thanks to cultural/internationalization issues, converting between dates and strings is almost always going to be a slower option... usually **much** slower... as well as introduce potential for error. The best option will tend to avoid those conversions.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Slower sure... much slower?   On 10K records 17ms.  You may note my top line < TheNextDay.   Just for fun  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=e6285f9e9e865cef4033087762e22d69

Answer (score 1):

Probably not more efficient, but I am a fan of using the correct functions for this sort of thing.

Also using the correct datatype, `datetime2` is the recommended datatype to use these days, and removes the pesky 3ms interval.

```
DECLARE @DateEnd DATETIME2(3) = '1/4/2011 16:43:22 PM';

SET @DateEnd = DATEADD(millisecond, -1, CAST(DATEADD(day, 1, CAST(@DateEnd AS DATE)) AS DATETIME2(3)));
```

Comment: @AaronBertrand I totally agree :) I was just answering the question as written